# prefixing a controller full of non-resourceful routes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

In rails `4.2` I have a controller that I want to fill with non resourceful routes something like

```
class TwilioController < ApplicationController
  def add_to_queue
  end

  def another_action
  end

end
```

I then want to access theese actions like so

`http://appdomain/twilio/add-to-queue`
and 
`http://appdomain.com/twilio/another-action`

I realise I could do this like so in the routes file

```
get 'twilio/add-to-queue', to: 'twilio#add_to_queue'
get 'twilio/another-action', to: 'twilio#another_action'
```

but is there a way of grouping all of them together so I don't have to explicitly add `twilio` at the beginning of each route.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have figured out a solution, it seems quite a succinct one.

```
scope path: 'twilio',  as: 't' do
   get 'add-to-queue', to: 'twilio#add_to_queue'
end
```

So i now have routes like:

```
t_add_to_queue GET  /twilio/add-to-queue(.:format)     twilio#add_to_queue
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution that works in Rails 3.2.

```
scope :path => :twilio, :controller => :twilio, :as => :twilio do
  get :add_to_queue
  get :another_action
  get :yet_another_action
end
```

`:path` adds `\twillio\...` to the URL
`:controller` maps all the nested routes to `TwillioController`
`:as` appends the URL helpers with `twillio_....`